# The following code doesn't perform as expected. The list does not render

Tags: angularjs-directive

The following code displays only the input box when run in the browser (Chrome). It seems to have broken when I attempted using the ng-controller directive.

```
     <!doctype html>
     <html ng-app="">
     <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js">  </script>
     <script>
        function SController($Scope) {
       $Scope.customers =
                 [{name:'John Smith',city:'Kingston'},
        {name:'Jane Doe',city:'Ocho Rios'},
        {name:'Brian Wade',city:'Negril'},
        {name:'John Barker',city:'Mandeville'} ];
        }
    </script>
      </head>
      <body ng-controller="SController">
        <div class="container">
          <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>  
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ person.name}} - {{ person.city }} </li>
      </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use `$scope`, not `$Scope`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first sight, it seems that you're using `$Scope` instead of the correct `$scope`. Replace those occurrences and try again.